# Docker image (jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest) with custom styles and custom background image

Tags: drools, redhat, jbpm, kie, azure-container-instances

We are hosting docker image (jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest) on Azure container service to bring the Rules capabilities into our project. We need to customize the look & feel of the UI like change the font color,background image etc.Is there a way to customize the docker image with custom styles and custom logos.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure Container Instance (ACI) to run your JBPM Docker container or AKS?

Also - are you using a MSQL version 5.7 as your backend container?

I am planning to do the same so thought we could exchange ideas/experiences.

Thanks
Ash